# Nginx serving file error 403 forbidden

Tags: nginx

To give first some history to this problem; I'm setting up a django site on digitalocean first copied using root and the django folder had as the owner root and I've since worked on fixing this and now the site it up and running but one image still has the 403 forbidden error.

I'm looking for a command that can change the rights of this file.

```
-rwxr----- 1 sammy sammy 566719 Jul  1 14:52 developer.jpg
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
chmod -R 777 folder_name

chmod -R 777 file.name //when You are in directory where this file exist
```

or

```
chmod -R 777 file_path/file.name
```

Comment: Changing the permissions to `777` is not good practice - see ['The problem with 777' on this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/357108/what-permissions-should-my-website-files-folders-have-on-a-linux-webserver).

Comment: Yes it's not, but he can check if it helps and then change them. Also for folder where are only images it's not so bad.

Answer (score 1):

Your NGINX user is likely using the `www-data` or a different user, to verify the user being used by NGINX in  a shell execute:

```
grep user /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

Then to change the file permissions:

```
chown www-data:www-data developer.jpg
```

Looking at your file permissions they also needed adjusted - [see this answer for recommended perms](https://serverfault.com/questions/345833/what-are-perfect-unix-permissions-for-usual-web-project-directories).

(may require `sudo`, replace `www-data` with your NGINX user)